# How could I line break after it reaches a certain number of characters

Tags: java

So for our project, we are supposed to have an input file that outputs to an output file. In the input file, you have "<left>" A SENTENCE "</left>". When you reach the "</left>" the method is supposed to end and if the sentence is 70 characters long it is supposed to line break. The first line should be indented by 9 spaces and every other sentence after that should be indented by 5 spaces. (We aren't supposed to use Arrays because it is an introductory class).

I have tried different types of loops and it prints it correctly but it does not correctly line break when it reaches 70 characters.

```
public static String fLeft(Scanner inp) {
    String content = "";
    String word = inp.next();
    String margin = "     ";
    int numLine = 0;

    while(!word.equals("</left>")){
        content = margin + content + word + " ";
        word = inp.next();
        if(numLine == 0){
            content = "     " + margin + content + word + " ";
            if(content.length() > 70){
                content = content + "\n";
                numLine = numLine + 1;
            }
        }
        if(numLine > 0){
            if(content.length() > 70){
                content = content + "\n";
                numLine = numLine + 1;
                break;
            }  
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

It compiles but it keeps running and doesn't end

Comment: You do **not** change the value of `firstLine` inside your `while(!firstLine)` loop. So if it starts, why do you expect it to end?

Comment: Even when changing that it still does not end. Should I do the first line and not the first line through numbers, like if(firstLine == 0){ Do something and if it isn't do another thing?

Comment: You re-set `content` inside your `while(firstLine)` loop, so it will never grow in length.

Comment: I suspect you mean the input file contains `<left>` _A number of words_ `</left>`.  (This would be similar to XML-style tags.) Do you need help editing your question to make that clear?

Comment: Yea I tried to add those tags but it removes then when it reads both of the < and > signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops becomes infinite in the following while condition

```
    while(numLine == 0){   // As numLine doesn't get chance to get updated you end up with infinite loop
        if(content.length() > 70){  // Initially this condition is false
            content = content + "\n";
            numLine = numLine + 1;   // So initially this statement is not reached
        }
    }
```

### Update

You can try my following solution

```
public static String fLeft(Scanner inp) {
    String content = "         ";
    int charCount = 0;
    // do until scanner has a word
    while (inp.hasNext()) {
        String word = inp.next(); // take the next word
        if (word.contains("</left>")) { // if word contains </left> this is going to be last word. contains is used to make sure we don't miss it if there are some chars before </left>
            int startIndexOfLastWord = 0;
            int endIndexOfLastWord = word.indexOf("</left>");
            String lastWord = word.substring(startIndexOfLastWord, endIndexOfLastWord); // remove the </left> from the last word if any
            charCount += lastWord.length();
            if (charCount <= 70) {
                // if the oldContent length is less than or equal to 70 just append the word
                content = content + word + " ";
            } else {
                // if the oldContent length is greater than 70 then append new line, margin and the word
                content = content + "\n" + "     " + word + " ";
            }
            break;
        } else {
            charCount += word.length();
            if (charCount <= 70) {
                // if the oldContent length is less than or equal to 70 just append the word
                content = content + word + " ";
            } else {
                // if the oldContent length is greater than 70 then append new line, margin and the word
                content = content + "\n" + "     " + word + " ";
            }
        }
        // reset charCount to 0 if it reaches 70.
        if (charCount >= 70) charCount = 0;
    }
    return content;
}
```

**P.S. If spaces should be included in 70 chars limit then you need to add spaces in the `charCount`.**

Comment: I see what you mean and I did change it, by putting it as an if statement rather than a while statement. Now it compiles but adds spaces at the beginning of the line so that the sentence reaches 70 characters then it starts a new line and repeats the same sentence in the same way.

Comment: can you please try the solution code I put in the update section

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine but I have not learned most of this, is there a way I could simplify this without using private methods or .indexOf. I just want to understand it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have commented out the codes and updated my answer. Hope it will help you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'd suggest replacing the inner `while` loops (`while (firstline)` and `while (!firstline)` with `if` statements, or rather, an `if`/`else` pair.  I would also suggest that the other inner `while` loop (`while(content.length() < numberChar)`) is also not exactly what you want, though that is one way to a solution for your assignment.

Also, you never break out of the second inner `while` loop (`while (!firstline)`); you simply add the same word again and again, with a newline every once in a while.  Thus, you never loop around the outer `while` loop, and never get past the second word.  (This is where you are see that it's stuck.

By the way, you read and check the first word (compare it to `"</left>"`, but never add it to your content, reading another word right away.

You do have most of the parts you need, but the program flow is what you are having trouble with.  Try writing out in pseudo-code (in pen on paper, perhaps) the steps you want to do, and take it from there.  Something like the following:

1. Search for the open tag (`<left>`).  Consider: What about everything before?
2. For each word:

   1. If it's the end tag (`</left>`), you're done.
   2. If it's the first word, append the first line margin, then the word.
   3. If the current line plus the new word is longer than the line length, append a line break followed by the margin, then the new word.  Remember to reset the current line length to the margin plus the new word.
   4. Otherwise, append the new word (preceded by a space) to your content.  Update the current line length.
3. Print out parsed content.

I think that's enough to set you well on your way.